# Completely removing an S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Accidentally deleted the contents of a bucket (S3) as well as the bucket itself. According to

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zu6Lw7TZYcU

charges can still be made if files are being logged to S3 but is this possible when there is no bucket?

Going to "Billing"

[image: aws billing]

there's still an active service. It is/was an S3 service but since the bucket has been deleted, going to S3 in the aws console:

[image: aws console]

gets to:

[image: no buckets]

The bucket has just been deleted a few minutes ago. Does it take time for the changes to be updated in the billing menu?

Is there any risk of additional charges on a bucket that has been deleted? The bucket has no endpoints and is not reachable.

Comment: Billing updates are not real-time. You have to wait, 1 day or so, for billing to be updated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to  s3 [Billing FAQ](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/?nc=sn&loc=7#Billing)

You will charged for the following types of s3 usage :

- Storage used
- Network Data Transferred In
- Network Data Transferred Out
- Data Requests
- Data Retrieval (S3 Standard-Infrequent Access (S3 Standard-IA) and S3 One Zone-IA storage classes )

You will only be charged if any of the above is true and as @marcin said billing changes takes Time to reflect.